# Sharepoint Breadcrumbs

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, breadcrumb, portalsitemapprovider

I attempted to add the **breadcrumbs** into my Sharepoint (Wiki) Page, I use code like this:

```
<asp:SiteMapPath runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" id="ContentMap" CssClass="BreadCrumbWrap" PathSeparator="&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;">
        <CurrentNodeStyle CssClass="BreadCrumbWrap" />
        <PathSeparatorStyle CssClass="BreadCrumbWrap" />  
        </asp:SiteMapPath>
```

But i didn't get the expected result. Now the breadcrumb leads to the library (folder), where the page is located.

**E.g. Home --> Library --> Page from library**

But my goal is to provide a breadcrumb, which leads to previous site - mother site.

**E.g. Home --> Mother site with a link to child site --> Child Site**

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for you:

```
<SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SiteMapProvider="SPContentMapProvider" CentralAdminSiteMapProvider="SPXmlAdminContentMapProvider">
    <PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
        <SharePoint:ClusteredDirectionalSeparatorArrow runat="server" />
    </PATHSEPARATORTEMPLATE>
</SharePoint:SPTitleBreadcrumb>
```

If the breadcrumb's path is too details, change `RenderCurrentNodeAsLink` to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I did something similar, I wrote on it here:

http://hardwiredmedia.com/creating-breadcrumbs-sharepoint-2013-document-library-pages/